# Remove text input value but not placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

Here's my code which is removing both value and placeholder. But I want to preserve the placeholder intact.

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Type something…">
<textarea id="desc" placeholder="Write description..."></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Click" onClick="submit_info();">
```

```js
function submit_info(){
    /* some functions to submit */
    $("#name").val(" ");
    $("#desc").val(" ");
}
```

The text field and textarea field is becoming blank.. removing everything.

I tried this as well which is removing nothing :

```
$("#name").removeAttr("value");
$("#desc").removeAttr("value");
```

Comment: `.val(" ")` isn't removing the value, you're setting it to a space

Comment: you have to remove the space in `val("")`

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder will only show up if there are no characters in the value. You are setting the value to "a space". Set it to an empty string instead.

i.e. change `" "` to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines

```
function submit_info(){
    $("#name").val("");
    $("#desc").val("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the value from the inputs entirely. Your current code is leaving the value as a single space (`' '`). Try this:

```
$("#name, #desc").val('');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u293263d/)